# Is there a way to restrict AWS Cognito users to only push to own SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

Consider thousands of users each authenticated by Amazon Cognito. 
Each of these users is to have it's own SQS queue. Is it possible to define an IAM role which restricts a user access to only it's own queue?

I'm thinking of somehow using Cognito credentials in combination with IAM variables to define a queuename based on a cognito user-id. Not sure where to start looking though.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't use Cognito to restrict access to a queue named after that identity. The IAM variable for the Cognito identity id is ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}, and that will be of the format region:uuid. I believe that colon causes problems in the SQS arn format.

Comment: Thanks. Will leave open while staying hopeful